# Finding entropy with two unknown probabilities, and maximizing it

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, optimization, entropy

$$S = \{ X, Y, Z, W\};\\P(X) = 0.1;\\P(Y) = 0.5;\\P(Z) = p;\\P(W) = q$$

1. I don't know how to find source (S) entropy with these 2 unknown $p$ and $q$ probabilities.
2. With which $p$ and $ q$ values this entropy gets maximum value and why?

Formula for 1 exercise is  $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i  \log_2 \frac{1}{p_i} $. 
So with my known data it looks like this $$0.1\log_2\frac{1}{0.1} + 0.5\log_2\frac{1}{0.5} + p\log_2\frac{1}{p} + q\log_2\frac{1}{q}= 0.832 +p\log_2\frac{1}{p}  +q\log_2\frac{1}{q}  $$

And the 2nd exercise:

$$0.1\log_2\frac{1}{0.1} + 0.5\log_2\frac{1}{0.5} + 2(0.2\log_2\frac{1}{0.2}) = 1.761$$

Does it seem right?

Comment: I know the formula for normal entropy. But still not sure how to maximize it.

Comment: I thought that i had to find those $p$ and $ q$ values before writing it in formula, I guess I was wrong. I edited my post with a formula. Still do not know, how to maximize it.

Comment: Sorry, just edited.

Comment: Use `\log` to get the logarithm notation right. You haven't justified your answer to #2, though. Unless your plan is to write "entropy is maximal when $p=q$ because Ilig Support told me so on the Internet"... you have to maximize the function, using calculus. The fact that $q = 0.4-p$ will help, reducing the problem to single-variable maximization on the interval $0<p<0.4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This more a comment than a solution, but i still lack reputation to post it there.
The formula you posted is the one for Shannon-Entropy. I assume that you know that:
$$P(X)+P(Y)+P(Z)+P(W)=1$$
While each of the summands is positive.
A coin that has S=Head,Tail and P(Head)=0.1 has an lower Entropy throw of just $(0.47)$ than one were both are sites are equally likely resulting in $(1.0)$ bit of Entropy. There is a tendency that overall Entropy is highest when all events are more equally likely. (Think about the Coin Example, see Example [here](http://webservices.itcs.umich.edu/mediawiki/lingwiki/index.php/Entropy))

This is **why** you need to choose values for $p$ and $q$ such that $p = q $ which leads to $p$ being $0.2$. $(p=\dfrac{1-P(X)-P(Y)}{2})$.

I recommend you to try calculating the Entropy for the Data "XYWZ" with changed (p, q) values. Since i am not 100% sure.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like you are right. I tried using different values for $p$ and $q$ for testing, but it seems like that 0.2 is the right answer.

Comment: Glad i did help you @Entropijus  , would not mind a upvote/being declared solution though :-) Do you understand how i came to this conclusion? Also you have an mistake in Solution 1. 0. vs 0.1 :)

Comment: You haven't said _why_ $p=q$ maximizes the entropy; "why" is a part of the question 2.

Comment: ok i take some time and clarify that,